# USACO Training – text submission giving me an error: "Error:_Main_method_not_found_in_class_test"

Tags: java

I'm on the first problem of the USACO training page, which asks you to submit a simple solution. Although my code compiles on my IDE, the USACO grader gives me an error, saying that main cannot be found.

> Run 1: Execution error: Your program exited with exit status `1'.

```
    ------ Data for Run 1 [length=4 bytes] ------
    1 1 
    ----------------------------

      Your program printed data to stderr.  Here is the data:
      -------------------
      Error:_Main_method_not_found_in_class_test,_please_define_the_main_method_as:
      ___public_static_void_main(String[]_args)
      or_a_JavaFX_application_class_must_extend_javafx.application.Application
      -------------------
```

My code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class test
{
  static class InputReader
  {

    BufferedReader reader;
    StringTokenizer tokenizer;

    public InputReader() throws FileNotFoundException{
      reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.in"));
      tokenizer=null;
    }

    String next() { //reads in the next String
      while (tokenizer ==null || tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()){
        try{
          tokenizer= new StringTokenizer(reader.readLine());
        }catch (IOException e) {
          throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
             return tokenizer.nextToken();
    }
    public int nextInt(){  //reads in the next int
      return Integer.parseInt(next());
    }
    public long nextLong(){  //reads in the next long
      return Long.parseLong(next());
    }
    public double nextDouble(){ //reads in the next double
      return Double.parseDouble(next());
    }


    public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException {

      InputReader r= new InputReader();
      PrintWriter pw= new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("test.out")));

      // your code here
      int a = r.nextInt();
      int b = r.nextInt();
      pw.println(a+b);

      pw.close();

  }        
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem might be that you are missing the identification comment at the top of your code.

As you can see from the [problem statement](https://train.usaco.org/usacotext2?a=17jrhThzWLf&S=grade), the header comment:

```
/*
ID: your_id_here
LANG: JAVA
TASK: test
*/
```

is required.

Comment: I have the comment, I just omitted it for this question for privacy reasons